# Casting Trigger.New to List<Case> in Trigger Framwork

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, casting, framework

We are using a trigger framework by [Kevin O'Hara](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) and I have a basic question about it. Why when I use Trigger.New inside one of the methods I have to cast it to a List of cases in order to use it?

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

    public CaseTriggerHandler() {
        this.setMaxLoopCount(35);
    }

    private static Boolean isMethod1 = false;

    protected override void beforeInsert(){
        if (!isMethod1) { 
            method1(Trigger.new); 
            isMethod1 = true;
        } 
    }

    private void method1() {

        for(Case c: (List<Case>)Trigger.New) {}      //<------------------

    }
}
```

If I write `for(Case c: Trigger.New)` then I get this error:

> Operation: Compiling: C:\Users\Dante\proj\src\classes\CaseTriggerHandler.cls
>   Timestamp: Sun, 27 Aug 2017 18:29:00
>      Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: classes/CaseTriggerHandler.cls: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Case (Line: 1324, Column: 9)

Can someone explain?

Comment: Next time please post the exact error message not one you paraphrase. It will help everyone to assist you better. I could be wrong but I do not recall an error message as you posted before as it usually appears as in the duplicate question. If that was indeed the exact error message please post a comment stating such as I would be interested in reproducing it since the answer may be different

Comment: I edited my question and you can see that I posted only the necessary part to avoid a long post.

The post you provided only says that the compiler couldn't detect that it was iterating over a list, I was looking for some other explanations.

Comment: Reopening as I cannot find any information on this error. This was the duplicate I marked it as: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33918/error-compile-error-loop-variable-must-be-of-type-sobject-at-line-7-column-13

Comment: check my answer and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to the framework you are using. It is standard compiler error. Below is the list of scenarios and explanations.

> **Scenario 1**: Trigger.New in Trigger, which works well as it is implicitly type casted to specific object, here is `Case`

*Result: it works wells and complies*

```
Trigger simpleTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    //works well
    for (Case a : Trigger.new) {
        // Iterate over each Case
    }
}
```

> **Scenario 2**: In the Trigger handler class and in a specific method, we are receiving specific list `List<Case>` as an argument, and trying to loop through the specific object.

*Result: it works wells and complies*

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler
{   
    public void onAfterInsert(List<Case> oldList, List<Case> newList)
    {
        //this works fine
        for(Case a:newList)
        {

        }
    }   
}
```

> **Scenario 3**: In a method, directly accessing `Trigger.new` which actually returns list of `SObject`. So, following code will works well.

*Result: it works wells and complies*

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler
{
    public void onAfterInsert()
    {
        //works well
        for(SObject a:Trigger.new)
        {
            if(a instanceOf Case)
            {
                Case caseObj = (Case) a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Scenario 4**: Type casting `Trigger.new` to list of Case

*Result: it works wells and complies*

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler
{
    public void onAfterInsert()
    {
        //works well
        for(Case a: (List<Case>)Trigger.new)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

> **Scenario 5**: Directly accessing `Trigger.new` without type casting to specific object.

***Result: Compile Error: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Case***

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler
{
    public void onAfterInsert()
    {
        //will not compile
        for(Case a: Trigger.new)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the answer is the same as the linked duplicate they just changed the error message from what we were used to

Comment: Reason is same, only I have explained in more detailed way

Comment: Right. Just stating that they changed the error message from what we were used to

Comment: Thank you Santanu for the break down! though it still doesn't explain why it's happening.

Comment: Basically Trigger.new returns List<SObject>, you need to type cast it to specific list like List<Case>, refer scenario 3, hope it makes sense!